# height of div doesn't go along with content next to it

Tags: css, html, height

I'll explain my problem:

I have a content div with 3 other divs in it:

```
                #content
#menu            #text          #sidebar
..          text...........      ------
..          text...........      ------
..          text...........      ------
            text...........      ------
            text...........
            text...........
```

That's how it looks like, the stripes in the #sidebar are displaying the content within it.
The sidebar has a green background that goes, that color goes through the whole website.

But what I want is that the length of the #sidebar will be the same as the lenght of the #text. It should then look like this:

```
                #content
#menu            #text          #sidebar
..          text...........      ------
..          text...........      ------
..          text...........      ------
            text...........      ------
            text...........      ------     
            text...........      ------
```

I'm not a professional programmer, so I hope someone can help me. I already tried some "logical" things like:
-setting the height of the #sidebar to auto
-setting the height of the #sidebar to 100% (which only makes it a bit longer)

Hopefully someone can help me! thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the website: http://colinch.com/52/

Comment: Have you tried searching for "css equal height columns"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following changes:

```
#content {
    position: relative;
}

#balk {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#balkgroen {
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can then remove the `float` on `#balk` and `#balkgroen` and also the `margin` on `#balk`.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much it worked!
This one is better than the other answer because now I dont have to set a height for the #content and everything changes automatic! 

I can't vote your answer yet but thanks alot

Comment: And what happens when #content is shorter than #balk?  Absolute positioning should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

if you define a height on the content div and give each of the tree the style="height:inherit" that should do it :)

Comment: That requires either a fixed height or a JavaScript solution setting the height when the page finished loading.

Comment: That worked but the other answer gave a solution where you dont have to define a height on the content div ;)